# How to get elements by class name on HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript

I've been thinking about why we cannot do this in javascript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class1').getElementsByClassName('class2')
```

This will not work, because the first `getElementsByClassName` call will give us an HTMLCollection, which doesn't have `getElementsByClassName` defined on it. Why is this? This would be a great function to use in this way, since it would let you get elements based on them having multiple different classes, not just one.

Is there any way to:

1. Get elements by class name in HTMLCollection
2. Get elements by multiple class names

Comment: How about `document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2")`

Comment: That's a decent solution. However, I think the classes should be separated by a comma, right?

Comment: Problem is HTML Collection does not have methods so either you would need to loop over each one individually and filter them and build your own collection or use a better method `querySelectorAll`

Comment: if you want to make it a little more complicated for yourself: Array.from(
document.getElementsByClassName('class1')).filter((item)=>{return Array.from(item.classList).includes('class2')})

Comment: No, selector syntax for an element with two classes is to have them next to each other with no spaces. Comma would mean either "class1" or "class2", which is not the same as **both** "class1" and "class2".

Comment: @Sandi, no the comma would be this OR that, not AND.

Comment: You can use for multiple class name on one element like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('container _full')` (separated with one space)

Answer (score 6):

Get by multiple class names:

```
document.querySelector('.someclass.otherclass'); // get first element that matches
document.querySelectorAll('.someclass.otherclass'); //get all elements that match
```

You can `querySelector*` any DOM element, not just `document`, in order to search in it.

Get by class name in HTMLCollection

```
[].filter.call(
    htmlCollection, element => [].includes.call(elements.classList, 'someclassname')
)
```

Neither HTMLCollection nor `.classList` are arrays, only array-like objects, hence the need for `.call`.

Comment: thanks, works perfect, just change ```elements.classList``` to ```element.classList```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get elements by class name in HTMLCollection :

   ```
   HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

   HTMLCollection.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function( name ){
       var all = [];
       this.forEach( function( el ){
            if( el )
                all.concat( el.getElementsByClassName( name ) );
       });
       return all;
   }
   ```
2. Get elements by multiple class names :

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2');
   ```

Please use the second for better performance.

Comment: First one is not correct, that is checking for children.

Comment: Yep, sry but that the syntax. @Sandi expected to write `document.getElementsByClassName('class1').filterHasClassName('class2')` I think.